# Web Scraping with Python - Code stopped at ~10000 rows not returning expected size of output

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping, request

I have below code written in Python to scrape a price list off the website.  According to "total results" there's supposed to be over 100k parts available, however when the output only returns ~10k.  Just wondering what might have caused this, any help appreciated!

```
import pandas as pd

import requests
query = 'GE Healthcare'
payload = {
        "facets":[],    
        "facilityId": 38451,
        "id_ins": "a2a3d332-73a7-4194-ad87-fe7412388916",
        "limit": 200,
        "query": query,
        "referer": "/catalog/Service",
        "start": 0,
        "urlParams":[]    
    }

r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
if r.status_code == 200:
    js = r.json()
    
df = pd.json_normalize(js["products"])
while len(df) < js["totalResults"] and len(df)<200000:
    payload["start"] += 200
    r = requests.post('https://prodasf-vip.partsfinder.com/Orion/CatalogService/api/v1/search', json=payload)
    if r.status_code == 200:
        df = pd.concat([df, pd.json_normalize(r.json()["products"])])
    else:
        break
    print(f"want: {js['totalResults']} got: {len(df)}")

df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\212677036\Documents\output_final.csv')
```

Comment: If I had to guess, you've exceeded the number of API calls you're allowed to make at a given time.

Comment: Maybe your getting rate-limited, your `break` will also stop the execution... why are you requesting the same data 200000 times?